# Jruby IRB up arrow(history) not working

Tags: ruby, rvm, jruby, irb

I'm using rvm on ubuntu 13.04

Using ruby 1.9.3, irb works fine. I can type a command, press enter, press up, and the command is there again.
However, using ruby 2.0.0 and jruby 1.7.3, the up arrow simply does nothing. As far as I can tell, readline is correctly installed.

Version info:

```
# ruby -v
  jruby 1.7.3 (1.9.3p385) 2013-02-21 dac429b on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_21-b02 [linux-amd64]

# irb -v
  irb 0.9.6(09/06/30)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$ rvm use 2.0.0
$ find $MY_RUBY_HOME -name readline*
/home/mpapis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/readline.so
$ ldd /home/mpapis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/readline.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff7e576000)
    libruby.so.2.0 => /home/mpapis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib64/libruby.so.2.0 (0x00007fc41de05000)
    libreadline.so.6 => /lib64/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007fc41db96000)
    libncurses.so.5 => /lib64/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007fc41d970000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc41d754000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fc41d54b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc41d347000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fc41d10b000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc41ce0c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc41ca5f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc41e49f000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fc41c82c000)
```